# Adding Quantity Change to Drop Down Menu

Tags: button, drop-down-menu, paypal

I am trying to make a pay now button for a registration form online.  Each individual has two options for payment.  If they are a member, they can pick and pay the member's rate for registering for this event.  If they are not members, they will pick the public's rate option for it.  That's fine.  It works great and it will ask them to either pay the member rate or public rate.

My question is, I would like to add another drop down button which would allow them to change the quantity of tickets they buy to this event.  So if they want to but 6 tickets, they select 6.  And if they are not members, in the next drop down box, they select Public.

I can add the second drop down menu, but it doesn't affect pricing at all, doesn't change the quantity.

Any help?

Comment: Can you add a copy of what you've tried yourself so far?

Answer (score 0):

If the price of each quantity is arbitrary, this can only be done with custom javascript.

Do your prices and quantities scale linearly? I.e. 1 for $10, 2 for $20, 3 for $30, 4 for $40 -- if so, you can use Add to Cart / Shopping Cart Buttons to handle the quantities.

Another potential hack is to multiply your current dropdown's number of entries with the number of your second menu.

```
General Public 1 ticket - $15
General PUblic 2 tickets - $25
Members Only 1 ticket - $10
Members Only 2 tickets - $20
```

Another way is to use 2 separate buttons, one listing the member rates and one listing the public rates.  This might actually be the good-enough path of least resistance.